# Can I read stdout from a process I do not control?

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, stdout

Several pre-existing applications write information to their console/stdout, even though they are run on a server without visible console windows.

Is there a way I can access a given process' stdout and stream from it? To reiterate: I do not have access to how these process are launched or work, I just want to be able to consume their stdout.

I'm working in VC++ on Windows. I'm sure I've seen console applications chain each other in this way before?

Comment: you can read the output of processes you start by making them write their output to a pipe, I don't think you can capture the output of a process that's already running

Comment: On Linux there are programs that use ptrace to reopen `stdout` of the target process to somewhere else. Presumably you can do the same thing on Windows with `CreateRemoteThread`, but if it breaks you get to keep both pieces.